# PageSource() gets different code than appium inspector code

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I am having a really hard time understanding the following problem, i have an app, i use appium inspector to see the elements, but when i use the elements, i get that the element is not found, therefore i printed the code using the driver.getPageSource() method, and i realized that the xml code that is created while running the app, is actually different to what appium inspector sees, what is the problem and how can it be solved? i could ask to the developers to fix it once i know the root cause, thanks in advance.

This is an example of a difference

Under `< XCUIElementTypeOther name = Picture, Left Rear Corner>` there are 4 more elements 2 StaticText, 2 Buttons (appium inspector) and on the the same element but in the java console, there are only 2  tags, so i do not see the 2 static text and the 2 buttons (which is what i want to click)

[image]

[image]

As you can see the code in the console is different to what i see in appium iinspector. this is for IOS app.

```
 while (driver.findElementsById("Additional Videos").size() == 0) {
            swipeScreenDown();
        }
        driver.getPageSource();
        WebElement additionalVideos = driver.findElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"Picture, Left Front Corner\"]");
        driver.getPageSource();
      List<WebElement> idf = additionalVideos.findElements(By.className("XCUIElementTypeButton"));
        driver.getPageSource();
        System.out.println(idf.size());
        driver.getPageSource();
        idf.get(0).click();
        driver.getPageSource();
```

Error got:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: It is difficult to view screenshots of code. Can you at least tell us what differences you see?

Comment: Under <XCUIElementTypeOther name = Picture, Left Rear Corner> there are 4 more elements 2 StaticText, 2 Buttons (appium inspector) and on the the same element but in the java console, there are only 2 <XCUIElementTypeOther> tags, so  i do not see the 2 static text and the 2 buttons (which is what i want to click)

Comment: Please put this information in your question. It is difficult for people to read this kind of stuff in comments

Answer (score 0):

`PageSource()` action can print the visual elements at the screen.

As per my understanding, You are currently performing `PageSource()` action when loading the screen.

You need to **click at the selected element**
[image]

After click on this element use `PageSource()` action.
You get that element in the log of the `PageSource()`.

Comment: it did not work, the element is not present but it should be,
 while (driver.findElementsById("Additional Videos").size() == 0) {
            swipeScreenDown();
        }
        driver.getPageSource();
        WebElement pic = driver.findElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"Picture, Left Front Corner\"]");
      List<WebElement> idf = pic.findElements(By.className("XCUIElementTypeButton"));
        driver.getPageSource();
        System.out.println(idf.size());
        idf.get(0).click();
        driver.getPageSource();

Comment: Please check my following code.

`while (driver.findElementsById("Additional Videos").size() == 0) {
            swipeScreenDown();
        }
        driver.getPageSource();
        WebElement additionalVideos = driver.findElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"Picture, Left Front Corner\"][1]");
additionalVideos.click();
        driver.getPageSource();
      List<WebElement> idf = additionalVideos.findElements(By.className("XCUIElementTypeButton"));
        driver.getPageSource();`